# How effect is the mathematica automatic machine learning function like `Classify`?

Tags: machine-learning

The documentation said use `Classify`, you will get state of the art machine learning result. But since the `Classify` function of Mathematica work much like a black box, we do not do manual feature engineering like imputation missing data, feature selection etc.

So I want to know is there any benchmark to show that Mathematica `Classify` function actually doing as good as or even better than using other machine library like sklearn and do manual feature engineering?

Comment: @IstvánZachar : No. I don't think they are duplicate. Both the question are asked by me. This question I want to know how accurate is the `Classify` function is, whether there is a benchmark to measure it.  Whether it actually do better than manual feature engineering approach like using python. The other question I want to know whether we can know the internal pre-processing mechanism. Whether we can specify the method like to explicit indicate the classify function to use in `Classify` function

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact that you've asked the other one, but I find them highly overlapping: you are interested in the internal processes of `Classify`. Furthermore, in both cases you did not explain what exactly is that you cannot find in the documentation (see e.g. Classify > Options > Method). I think it would be rather vague to compare any reasonable banchmarking results considering the many options you can choose for such a high-level function. Again, this boils down to the internals of the function.